# How long & at what temp do I cook stuffed pork sirloin roast?

Tags: roasting, pork

I have a supermarket, stuffed pork sirloin roast.  I want to make it today.  It wieghs 2.80#  How long and at what temp do I cook it, and should it be covered or uncovered?  I've never made one of these before, and am unfamiliar with how to prepare roasts, so I have to know every little detail.

Comment: "Every little detail" is very simple - get a meat thermometer. I am sure other people will be able to give you guesses, but depending on the shape of the meat, the type of your oven, and the type of vessel you are cooking it in, they can be very far off.

Comment: Hi Leah, this appears to be more of a recipe request than anything else. I would recommend searching the internet or reading the label of the roast for instructions on how to cook it (most of the prepackaged ones have a label on the side with one). We don't really answer recipe requests since they are not constructive, but if you run into any problems cooking up your roast come back and ask and the community will surely be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a recipe for stuffed pork loin that I have made using anything from a 3 to 6 pound loin. It's been butterflied, pounded flat, stuffing spread on, then rolled tight & tied with twine.

I bake it for 20 minutes at 475 degrees F, then for an additional 30 to 40 minutes at 325 degrees F, whether the roast is 3 pounds or 6 pounds, and then I just check with a meat thermometer to be sure the internal temp is where I want it.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what the stuffing is: if it's minced meat you'll have to cook it through to 70C; unfortunately that's a temperature that will mean the pork is horribly overcooked. Best way would be to pasteurise it at a lower temperature (57-60C) sous vide and then brown afterwards but obviously that's dependant on you having the right equipment.